# Java database error : java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Bad packet type

Tags: java, oracle

I randomly got this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Bad packet type
```

I did some research, someone suggested a solution:

> To correct this problem we have to ensure that only one thread of execution was making use of the JDBC driver at a time through the same Connection OR upgrade to a later version of the driver.

Can anyone guide me in how to ensure that only one thread of execution was making use of the JDBC driver at a time ?

Comment: What type of application is it?  Is it a web application?  What is the threading model of your application?  How are you managing your connections?  Are you using JDBC directly, through something like Spring, through an ORM?

Comment: Yes, it is a web application. We are using JDBC directly.

Comment: Web application, as in you're using raw servlets?  And so how are you obtaining a Connection?  In the `doGet()` method of your servlet?  When the servlet is instantiated (e.g. in the constructor)?

Comment: The connection is established doGet() and it is instantiated onload on the application

Comment: Can you confirm the port number is correct. Here is a link that talks about it. https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=889611.

Comment: Yes, the port is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved the problem by closing the connection of a preparedStatement, instead of the Database connection itself.

Use:

```
ps.getConnection().close();
```

instead of :

```
conn.close();
```

Comment: That solution makes no sense, as that should be the exact same connection.