# solr dataimport handle is returning IO Error: Bad packet type after Oracle DB upgraded from 11g to 12c

Tags: oracle, jdbc, solr

I am facing very strange issue. Till yesterday were using Solr 4.6 and Oracle 11g and our dataimporthandler was working fine.

Today we upgraded oracle from 11.2 to 12.1 and now if we are trying run dataimporthandler it is returning below exception.

2017-03-02 12:39:59,594 [Thread-62] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder - Exception while processing: ALL document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Bad packet type
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:63)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.hasnext(JdbcDataSource.java:368)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.access$600(JdbcDataSource.java:254)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator$1.hasNext(JdbcDataSource.java:289)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorBase.getNext(EntityProcessorBase.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:408)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:323)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:231)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:476)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:457)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Bad packet type

Any sort of guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Manmohan.

Comment: can you check this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01012_not_logged_on.htm

Comment: Thanks your answer. Sorry but I had pasted wrong error log. I just updated with correct error log. The error I am getting is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Bad packet type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025809/java-database-error-java-sql-sqlexception-io-exception-bad-packet-type

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: We are using ojdbc7 and JDK 7.
We seem to have fixed the issue. Its very strange but after upgrading oracle version, idle_time was getting expired while dataimport handler was still running and dataimport handler was hanging with the above error.
Our DBA suggested to make idle_time to INFINITE and now dataimport handler is fine.

Thank you all for your time.